# Want to update or return false instead of insert in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I update a field with `saveField` method in cakephp.

**Example:**

```
$this->Attachment->id = $id;
$updateResult = $this->Attachment->saveField('dispatched', '1');
```

Now if the value of `$id` not exist in db then `saveField` insert a new record in database. But I want to update record instead of new insert. if the value of `$id` is not exist in db then I want return false from `saveField`

How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check if the record exists

```
if ($this->Attachment->findById($id)) {
    $this->Attachment->id = $id;
    return $this->Attachment->saveField('dispatched', '1');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your save in a conditional:

```
$this->Attachment->id = $id;
if(isset($id) {
  //your save here
  $updateResult = $this->Attachment->saveField('dispatched', '1');
}else{
  return false;
}
```

Update after comment:

So do a count and use this as the test instead:

```
$settings = array(
  'conditions'=>array(
    'Atachment.id'=>$id;
  )
);
$test = 0;
$test = $this->Attachment->find('count', $settings);

if($test >0 {
   //your save here
} else {
  //return false here
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: Let $id = 5. But there is no record exist with id=5 in db then I want return false.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment